# Golang json parsing

Tags: json, encoding, go

I have a json string like this:

```
    {
"offset":4224368,
"fcn_addr":4224368,
"fcn_last":4224408,
"size":2,
"opcode":"add byte [rax], al",
"bytes":"0000",
"type":"add",
"type_num":17,
"type2_num":0,
"flags":[
"entry0",
"sym._start",
"section_end..plt",
"section..text"
],
"comment":"WzEzXSB2YT0weDAwNDA3NTcwIHBhPTB4MDAwMDc1NzAgc3o9MTA5OTE4NiB2c3o9MTA5OTE4NiByd3g9LXIteCAudGV4dA=="
},
{
"offset":4224370,
"fcn_addr":4224368,
"fcn_last":4224408,
"size":2,
"opcode":"add byte [rax], al",
"bytes":"0000",
"type":"add",
"type_num":17,
"type2_num":0
}}
```

and i have created a struct

```
type DisassembleOutput struct {
    offset, fcn_addr, fcn_last, size int
    opcode, bytes string
}
```

i just want to save this json into the struct like this one.
So the problem is in unmarshaling with encoding/json lib, i can't get it to work ( **error is always unable to unmarshal json data into main.Disas structure**).
I'm a golang newbie btw.

**EDIT:**

This is actually the problem http://play.golang.org/p/cpYsnXa-b9. 
how to parse one by one items fromm [{ ... }]

Answer (score 1):

[Export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the field names by starting them with an uppercase letter:

```
type DisassembleOutput struct {
  Offset, Fcn_addr, Fcn_last, Size int
  Opcode, Bytes                    string
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/9qMfGGnFS_)

Comment: Thats helpful, thanks! and just one more thing, what would i have to do if json was like this [ { samejson here } ] ? Thanks again!

Comment: I have updated the code on play golang with the actual question regarding my last comment, here's  link http://play.golang.org/p/cpYsnXa-b9

Comment: Your example on the playground is not valid JSON as the error message indicates. Not sure what's intended.

Comment: It is a valid json, and i found a solution using https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/. Thanks for answers anyway!

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com to ensure the JSON is valid.